# i18n.locale is an array now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, internationalization

I have been turning locales to strings by calling to_s on the locale. For example `I18n.locale.to_s` which would return `se` or `de`.

But now I have noticed that I18n.locale.to_s returns `["se"]` or `["de"]`. Have they turned into arrays? It looks kinda like it's a symbol of an array. Weird, because I get syntax error on `:[:se]`.

This happened when I upgraded Debian to 7, which upgraded ruby to 1.9. My rails versions is 3.2.

Is there a way to get the string `"se"` or similar from a locale? Without doing the obvious and ugly hack of manually removing the first and last two characters, of course.

Comment: no they did not return array it may be some problem on your app `irb(main):001:0> I18n.locale.to_s
=> "en"`

Comment: I just tested in Ubuntu 13.04 with Ruby 1.9.2 and I cannot duplicate this. What does `.class` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy to test.

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > I18n.locale.class
 => Symbol
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realise the problem wasn't actually I18n but String.scan